# a function to org-mime-subtree then org-mime-HTMLize?

Tags: org-mime

I'm trying to streamline my email-sending tasks into my org-mode workflow, and I’d like a way to quickly email a subtree to someone.

I'm trying to create a function that will:

1. org-mime-subtree
2. insert my signature (including a link)
3. org-mime-HTMLize

Here's what I have

```
(defun org-mime-subtree-and-HTMLize ()
  "org-mime-subtree and HTMLize"
  (interactive)
  (org-mime-subtree)
(insert "\nBest,\nS.\n---\n 
[[http://www.newyorkwritersintensive.com/][newyorkwritersintensive.com]]")
  (org-mime-htmlize))
```

When I run it, I get the error "wrong number of arguments."

Comment: The function `org-mime-htmlize` requires an argument, which appears should have been optional for non-interactive use, but is mandatory.  There are conditions for if there is an `arg` or if there is no `arg`, however, the function will not work within `elisp` unless it has an `arg`.  It appears that a simple `t` would suffice.  So try it with `t` and see if that fixes your issue:  `(org-mime-htmlize t)`.  However, I have never used this library and just Googled the function, so I'm not sure if that is all you need.

Comment: Hmm, doing `(org-mime-htmlize t)` changes the whole message to monospace font. I just want a function that will do the same thing as I get when I manually run `org-mime-subtree` and `org-mime-htmlize`.

Comment: In that case, you may wish to rewrite the function `org-mime-htmlize` so that you can use it in `elisp` without the *mandatory* argument -- i.e., you will need to make the argument *optional*.  To do that, you can copy the entire function over to your user customization file -- place a preceding *require* statement followed by the new function with the same name using *&optional arg* instead of *arg* -- like this:  `(require 'org-mime) (defun org-mime-htmlize (&optional arg) . . . [insert the rest of the entire function without making any changes]`  Save your changes and restart Emacs.

Comment: I did that, but for some reason it's still applying monospace styling to the email. It doesn't do this when I run org-mime-htmlize manually. http://pastebin.com/3MRh22NG

Comment: Now that you have rewritten the function, you no longer need to use `(org-mime-htmlize t)` -- i.e., just use `(org-mime-htmlize)` and you should no longer encounter an error message "wrong number of arguments".  I suspect that the `arg` (which is now *optional* thanks to the rewrite of the function) being set to `t` is what causes the behavior you wish to avoid.

Comment: You are correct, it works!

Comment: Here's the code if you want to use it for an official answer. http://pastebin.com/tV3pJaCW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue described by the original poster is caused by using `org-mime-htmlize` on a non-interactive basis -- i.e., the single argument is *mandatory* (when using said function on a non-interactive basis), rather than *optional*.  The solution is to rewrite the function so that the argument is *optional*:

```lisp
(require 'org-mime)

(defun org-mime-htmlize (&optional arg)
"Export a portion of an email body composed using `mml-mode' to
html using `org-mode'.  If called with an active region only
export that region, otherwise export the entire body."
  (interactive "P")
  (require 'ox-org)
  (require 'ox-html)
  (let* ((region-p (org-region-active-p))
         (html-start (or (and region-p (region-beginning))
                         (save-excursion
                           (goto-char (point-min))
                           (search-forward mail-header-separator)
                           (+ (point) 1))))
         (html-end (or (and region-p (region-end))
                       ;; TODO: should catch signature...
                       (point-max)))
         (raw-body (concat org-mime-default-header
                           (buffer-substring html-start html-end)))
         (tmp-file (make-temp-name (expand-file-name
                                    "mail" temporary-file-directory)))
         (body (org-export-string-as raw-body 'org t))
         ;; because we probably don't want to export a huge style file
         (org-export-htmlize-output-type 'inline-css)
         ;; makes the replies with ">"s look nicer
         (org-export-preserve-breaks org-mime-preserve-breaks)
         ;; dvipng for inline latex because MathJax doesn't work in mail
         (org-html-with-latex 'dvipng)
         ;; to hold attachments for inline html images
         (html-and-images
          (org-mime-replace-images
           (org-export-string-as raw-body 'html t) tmp-file))
         (html-images (unless arg (cdr html-and-images)))
         (html (org-mime-apply-html-hook
                (if arg
                    (format org-mime-fixedwith-wrap body)
                  (car html-and-images)))))
    (delete-region html-start html-end)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char html-start)
      (insert (org-mime-multipart
               body html (mapconcat 'identity html-images "\n"))))))

(defun mime-send-mail ()
"org-mime-subtree and HTMLize"
(interactive)
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (org-mime-subtree)
  (insert "\nBest,\nS.\n")
  (org-mime-htmlize))
```